# Kill a repeating AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX request that looks like this:

```
var statistics = "link-to-a-JSONP";

function team_stats(json) {
   alert(json);
}

(function stats() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: statistics + '?callback=jsonp',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'team_stats',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            data: {},
            success: function(data) {
              var test += '<div>' + data + '</div>';
              $(".content").append(test);

              /* a close button that closes the tab and kills the request */
              $("#closeStats").on("click", function() {
                    stats.abort();
                });
            },
            complete: function() {
              setTimeout(stats, 15000);
            }
       });
})();
```

This works great and the request repeats itself every 15 seconds. Now, I want to kill the request when I click a certain button (as shown). The compiler says that the fragment stats.abort() is not a function and continues the loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm assuming you have stats.abort() defined somewhere. Try moving the code for attaching the click event to #closeStats outside of the stats function. I'm pretty sure you only want to attach this once (not every time call the ajax call is successful)and should give it access to the correct content for stats.abort().

Comment: What is "stats"??If has NOTHING to do with the Ajax call, it is a function.

Comment: stats is the name of the function that defines my AJAX request. It is successfully called from within complete, setting it as part of setTimeout, so I don't understand why it cannot be called inside success as well.

Comment: because the function has nothing to do with the Ajax call or the timeout. It is like closing the front door in order to close the refrigerator door. They have NOTHING in common other than the ajax call resides inside the function.

Comment: @KarlP.Galvez I don't have it defined anywhere else. True, the call doesn't always return success, but in this case success brings values and HTML elements that can only be closed from within the same loop.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for the explanation! How would you kill the request then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling abort on a function. Functions do not have abort.

You want to kill the setTimeout. So you need to hold a reference to the timer.

```
(function () {
    var timer;
    function foo () {
        console.log(new Date());
        timer = window.setTimeout(foo,1000);  //<-- store a reference to the timeout
    }

    function killTimer() {
        if (timer) window.clearTimeout(timer);
    }

}());
```

If you want to also abort an active Ajax request, you need to hold a reference to that too.

```
xhr = $.ajax(...);
...
xhr.abort();
```

Comment: This is absolutely correct! I knew I was doing something wrong. So I need to kill the timeout instead... Thank you very much :)